# A smooth fiber bundle $S^1\times S^3\to \Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is a closed surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, fiber-bundles

Consider the map $\pi:S^1\times S^3\to S^3\to S^2$, where the first map is projection and the second map is Hopf fibration. This is a torus bundle over $S^2$. I am trying to show the converse: if $p:S^1\times S^3\to \Sigma$ is a smooth fiber bundle then it must be isomorphic to $\pi$.

Here is my attempt: let $F$ be a fiber of $p$. From the homotopy exact sequence of $p$, and using $\chi(F)\chi(\Sigma)=\chi(S^1\times S^3)=0$, I've shown that $p$ must be a torus bundle over $S^2$. But how can we show that $p$ must be isomorphic to $\pi$?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out the argument, but it seems to me the fundamental point of the argument should be that fiber bundles over $S^2$ are in bijection with maps $[S^1, \operatorname{Diff}(S^1 \times S^1)]$ and this set is $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \times \operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. This calculation comes from the fact that up to isotopy all diffeomorphisms are determined by a pair of rotations about either axis along with a diffeomorphism that induces the linear map on homology. I think it should not be too hard of a task to completely calculate the corresponding total

Comment: spaces and manually check that only one of them has total space $S^1 \times S^3$.

Comment: Your argument that it must be a torus bundle over $S^2$ is flawed. A torus bundle over $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma$ bundles over a torus have Euler characteristic zero. It is true that if $S^1\times S^3$ is an orientable surface bundle over an orientable surface, then it must be a torus bundle over $S^2$, but the argument is more involved.